# mongodb.lock permission denied can't start systemctl even if correct permissions

Tags: mongodb, permissions, redhat, systemctl

I am getting permission denied on the mongodb.lock when I run `service mongodb start` even though the folder owner is mongodb and file permissions are set correctly or even 777.

This state occurred after a mongo import command which failed due to a lack of storage space. I believe that mongodb crashed and ended up in a corrupted state. I saw similar errors before that I fixed by setting the logging path back to where it was before when /var/log got filled up to max capacity (due to the dbpath also being in /var, which I now changed to /mongo_data).

Here's a screenshot of me trying to run `mongodb --repair` (same error as when I would start using `service`:
[image: mongodb repair output error]

PS: I am not actually asking for a solution, I am writing this question with the "solution". If you know the cause and have the time to explain, please feel free!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have is for RHEL 8. The only fix I could find was to reinstall mongodb completely `sudo yum remove mongodb-org* && sudo yum install mongodb-org`. At first I tried to remove without the asterisk (*), but it seems like there was still some corrupted files causing the same permission error regarding the lock file to occur.